# true privacy with safegmail

Tags: gmail, encryption

*not sure if this is the best SE site for this question*

SafeGmail is a way to encrypt email body test with PGP. Once you click "send" the email is encrypted and sent as encrypted text. This seems safe enough once the email is sent. The recipient only ever receives the encrypted message.

However, now that gmail does this "auto saving" thing, every letter I type as I'm typing an email gets sent up to gmail and saved in my Draft box. Does SafeGmail deal with this? Since my email isn't encrypted until I "send" it, the unencrypted message is still always being uploaded to Gmail through auto-saves.

Comment: SafeGmail is what? A browser extension? [security.se] _might_ be a better place for this question.